# How can I set table column widths in an MVC view?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the default, design-time scaffolded view for a list, in an MVC4 Razor app. Each column is as follows:

```
<td class="col-code">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
</td>
```

I have tried adding a `width` attribute to the TD's, but seems to have no effect. The only thing that works is styling the INPUT rendered by `DisplayFor`, but I can't do that here as I have nowhere to set html attributes.

Comment: Strange behavior indeed, any ideas why the inline style <td style="width:10px;"> is not overriding the default? and where is the default coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using simple HTML tables, you should add a header to your columns using the `th` tag that can then be styled to the desired width.

For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="col1">First col</th>
    <th class="col2">Second col</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third cell</td>
    <td>Fourth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

can be used with this CSS code:

```
.col1 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col2 {
    width: 25%; /* not very useful in this case as 'col2' will take the remaining */
}
```

Comment: This is what I have done, but I was hoping to find a way to inline the widths and avoid having to have CSS specific to just one table. However, a scoped style is probably good here and neater than inline.

Comment: You could maybe inline the widths directly in the `th` tags instead of the `td` ones. But the `width` attribute is now deprecated so you will have to go with something like `<th style="width:75%">`...

Comment: I tried such very quickly, hehe, only in the Chrome dev console, with no effect. I'm going with css. I'll accept soonish if no superhero better answers come up.

Comment: @ProfK: using MVC 5 VS2013 Bootstrap, with long strings and no whitespace, need additional style attributes for the `th`, e.g.: `width: 600px;word-break: break-all; white-space: normal;`

Comment: This didnot work for me in IE 11. My header width are constant but my rows width expands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well in a view:

```
**@model List<Student>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }
<h2>NEW VIEW Index</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">
         ID          </th>
        <th scope="col">
            FirstName
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            LastName
        </th>
     </tr>
     @foreach (var element in Model) {
    <tr>    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => element.ID)</td>  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => element.FirstName)</td>   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => element.LastName)</td>    </tr>
}
    </table>**
```

The result is nice:

[image]

Comment: Can you please describe it further? Where do you define the class "table" and scope "col1" and "col2"?