# Table Column Width Percentage Editing with Images

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I have many different view pages with many tables widths. Example:

- View 1 Product.cshtml : first column has 25% width, second column has
  75% width
- View 2 Customer.cshtml: first column has 40% width, second column has
  60% width

So utilizing resource, I edited csstemplate. [How can I set table column widths in an MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074901/how-can-i-set-table-column-widths-in-an-mvc-view)

With only text, the solution works great.
However when I add images, it totally ignores the table width percentages, making the image look very large. How would I resolve this and keep image at only 25%?

Note: supplied a static image for now to test, will be made variable later.

**Site.css**

```
.col1 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col2 {
    width: 75%; 
}
```

**Product Index.cshtml**

```
@model IPagedList<ElectronicsStore.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
    int counter = 0;
}
@using X.PagedList;
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core;


<table class="table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col1">
               Product Image
            </th>
            <th class="col2">
               Product Name
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts)
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">
                <img src="~/images/TV.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true" />
            </td>
            <td class="col2">
                @item.ProductName
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>



@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?  I'm trying it and it does not work, so my image causes the table to resize and the other columns get squashed. Perhaps I'm implementing it wrong though, can you share the css style that is working for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it doesn't related to **ASP.NET Core MVC**. It just about `Html` and `CSS`.
All you need to do is add this CSS style to your stylesheet:

```
.col1 img { width: 100% }
```

Comment: I'm trying this and it does not work.  in the style should I have ".col1 { width: 75%; } and then another line as you show: ".col1 img { width: 100% }?

Comment: @PaulGibson If you use the layout in the question, yes